# Check-in Database project from Visual Studio to Git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, push, git-push

I created a Database project in my solution in Visual Studio 2015. When I'm trying to push this project into the git repository, I'm facing the following issue:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: unpacking
>   the sent packfile failed on the remote

Has anyone encountered similar issue while pushing to git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Security folder files in the database project. When I tried to check-in only the sql files of the project and ignored the Security folder files, everything worked fine.